# Was there any treaty during WWI and II with the world countries and Sir Henry Dunant's Red Cross to respect those with Red Cross?

Tags: treaties

Sir Henry Dunant created the assembly of Red Cross to help the victims of a battle zone.

During WWI and II was there any treaty with all the countries to respect the volunteers and employees of Red Cross?

Henry Dunant was awarded the Knight of the Legion of Honour. Here is the wiki. commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Henri_Dunant

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=Any+treaty+with+Red+cross+during+wwi&oq=Any+treaty+with+Red+cross+during+wwi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61.17605j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: https://www.icrc.org/en/document/international-committee-red-cross-first-world-war-0    Geneva Convention. Got the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Sir Henry? He was a Swiss citizen. I can't find anywhere he was knighted in the UK.

Comment: This question would be stronger with more research.  When was the assembly of the red cross created? Who were signatories? What is the text? Biographical details on Durant & his honours.

Comment: Please do not respond in comments.  Comments request clarifications; clarifications should be edited into the question.  Questions should contain everything needed for research.

Comment: I admire Dunant too, but a holder of the Legion d'Honneur is not a British knight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Hague Convention of 1899](http://www.opbw.org/int_inst/sec_docs/1899HC-TEXT.pdf) states:

> **Art. 21.** The obligations of belligerents with regard to the sick and
>   wounded are governed by the Geneva Convention of 22 August 1864,
>   subject to any modifications which may be introduced into it.
>
> **Art. 60.** The Geneva Convention applies to sick and wounded interned
>   in neutral territory.

The [Geneva Convention of 1864](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/ihl/INTRO/120?OpenDocument) states (**my emphasis**)

> **Article 1.** Ambulances and military hospitals shall be recognized as neutral, and as such, protected and respected by the belligerents as long as they accommodate wounded and sick.
>   Neutrality shall end if the said ambulances or hospitals should be held by a military force.
>
> **Art. 2.** Hospital and ambulance personnel, including the quarter-master's staff, the medical, administrative and transport services, and the chaplains, shall have the benefit of the same neutrality when on duty, and while there remain any wounded to be brought in or assisted.
>
> **Art. 6.** .... Evacuation parties, and the personnel conducting them, shall be considered as being absolutely neutral.
>
> **Art. 7.**   A distinctive and uniform flag shall be adopted for hospitals, ambulances and evacuation parties. It should in all circumstances be accompanied by the national flag. An armlet may also be worn by personnel enjoying neutrality but its issue shall be left to the military authorities. ***Both flag and armlet shall bear a red cross on a white ground***.

This clearly indicates that the traditional emblem of the International Red Cross shall designate medical personnel, and that medical personnel evacuating or treating wounded combatants are neutral.

Note however that it is ***medical personnel suitably identified and employed*** who are provided for - not just International Red Cross personnel.

The Armed Forces of the United States were for a long period governed by the [Lieber Code of 1863](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/applic/ihl/ihl.nsf/ART/110-20116?OpenDocument) rather than international treaties:

> **Art. 116.** Honorable belligerents often request that the hospitals within the territory of the enemy may be designated, so that they may be spared. An honorable belligerent allows himself to be guided by flags or signals of protection as much as the contingencies and the necessities of the fight will permit.

The Lieber Code additionally goes into great detail surrounding the proper handling of *Flags of Truce* arranged between opposing commanders. But because it was a unilateral declaration of rules of engagement for Union forces, it is constrained to speak in more general terms than subsequent international treaties.

**See also:**

- [What Laws of War Existed before the Modern International Treaties and Conventions?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/what-laws-of-war-existed-before-the-modern-international-treaties-and-convention)
- [Medical Personnel fighting on the Battlefield (WW2)](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20818/medical-personnel-fighting-on-the-battlefield)